# Where are intervals stored?

Tags: rxjs

If I fire the following function 10 times

```
createInterval() {

  var someInterval =  interval(10000).pipe( take(1)).subscribe(
    _intervalValue => 
    {
      console.log(" Interval Fired" + new Date().toISOString());
    });

}
```

I get 10 intervals that will console log 10 times. How do I know that I have 10 intervals?
Where can I access these, it's like they exist mysteriously somewhere.

Comment: They're internal to the library. `interval` creates an object that has state and chainable functions like `pipe`. You could try printing it and poking around at the properties, but I wouldn't mess with it in a serious application. Use the public interface provided by the library only.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know that I have 10 intervals?

Let's simplify using numbers instead of Observables:

```js
function createNumber() {
  const someNumber = Math.random();
  console.log(`Number Created: ${someNumber}`);
}

for(let x=0; x<10; x++) {
  createNumber();
}
```

And re-ask the same question: **"How do I know that I have 10 numbers?"**

Well... you don't.  Not unless you're saving a reference to them!

So let's have the function return a reference to the number:

```js
function createNumber() {
  const someNumber = Math.random();
  console.log(`Number Created: ${someNumber}`);
  return someNumber;
}

let myNumbers = [];
for(let x=0; x<10; x++) {
  myNumbers.push(createNumber());
}

console.log(`I know I have ${myNumbers.length} numbers!`);
```

This behavior is no different for observables.  If you want know you have 10 intervals, you need to keep track of them:

```js
function createInterval() {
  return interval(1000)
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(
      () => console.log(`Interval Fired: ${ new Date().toISOString() }`)
    );
}

let mySubscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
for(let x=0; x<10; x++) {
  mySubscriptions.push(createInterval());
}

mySubscriptions.forEach(
  sub => sub.unsubscribe()
);
```

Note: by calling `.subscribe()` you are returning a `Subscription`, not an `Observable`.  It is often convenient to have functions return the observable, and let consumers of the function call `.subscribe()`:

```js
function createInterval() {
  return interval(1000).pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(() => console.log(`Interval Fired: ${ new Date().toISOString() }`))
  );
}

let myObservables: Observable<number>[] = [];
for(let x=0; x<10; x++) {
  myObservables.push(createInterval());
}

const mySubscriptions = myObservables.map(
  obs => obs.subscribe()
);

// then later on, you can unsubscribe
mySubscriptions.forEach(
  sub => sub.unsubscribe()
);
```

Comment: Hey BizzyBob! Thanks for your time in the reply. I was hoping that rxjs has some way to do this for us, but if I have to role my own, no problem. I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel. Cheers!